# ASP.Net input submit button not submitting form

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

I have an asp.net page with two input submit buttons, and then a div that's runat server. I programmatically fill that div with another input submit button on page load. (I need to do that part in the code behind, because the value of the button is dependent on certain factors that happen in the code.) However, THAT button that is now a child of the div does not submit the page form. When I click it, nothing happens.

```
<form runat="server">
<input type="submit" value="OK"/>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
<div id="holder" runat="server"></div>
</form>
```

In the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     holder.innerHTML = "<input type='submit' value='Complete'/>"
}
```

When the page loads and I inspect the DOM, everything is fine. The button inside the div is identical to the buttons outside the div - but it won't submit the form.

I didn't copy the code exactly - I just gave you an idea of what I'm doing, because I know that I don't have a mistake in my code, it's an issue with the fact that I'm creating the button programatically. But I don't understand why that should affect it!

Ideas, anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include the rendered output?

Comment: I added the same code and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this it's tested :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        holder.InnerHtml = "<input type='submit' value='Complete'/>";
    }
```

and the html body is :

```
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    <div id="holder" runat="server"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: How is this any different than what I posted, aside from the html capitalization? (I did it correctly in the code editor...)

Comment: Yes whatever you write is right, the same code i used is working on my side.

Comment: just try to create a new page then do the same again hope will work and the another option is to do it by using javascript - we can call a javascript function on this button click and this function will contain code to  submit the form.